# can't enable the Python virtual environment while creating an app on Mac

Tags: python, macos, installation, virtualenv

I am following instruction to create Mac app with Python.
I was installing Virtualenv as a part of it, as [here](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/install-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper-on-mac-os-x/) says.
I successfully did till second step; pip install, bash_profile.
But when I try to Enable the virtual environment part, I get a. no file or directory / b&c. command not found, for each step.

By the way, this is the first time I heard .bash_profile, so the script is empty except what I did at the second step.

How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 5):

Follow simple steps

1. `pip install virtualenv`
2. `virtualenv <venv name>`
3. `source venv/bin/activate`

another way of creating a venv in python 3 only

1. `python -m venv <venv name>`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Worked like a charm thanks, this should be an accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you read [Virtualenv User Guide](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide.html).

1. Install virtualenv by using `pip install virtualenv`
2. `virtualenv ENV` to create virtual environment.

   Where `ENV` is a directory to place the new virtual environment.
3. `source bin/activate` to activate script.
4. And type `deactivate` to undo the changes.

[virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

> Add three lines to your shell startup file (`.bashrc`, `.profile`,
> etc.) to set the location where the virtual environments should live,
> the location of your development project directories, and the location
> of the script installed with this package:

```
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PROJECT_HOME=$HOME/Devel
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the startup file.